# I am using some few pkgs in my project,which are not compatible with flutter web,my app crashes when try to run on web,

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web

I am using some dart pkgs in my project,which are not compatible with flutter web,my app crashes when try to run on web,
these are some example of pakages i am using,
permission_handler: ^9.2.0
flutter_speed_dial: ^5.0.0+1
path_provider: ^2.0.9
local_auth: ^1.1.11